# Plotly chart bars are still shown in stack with barmod defined to group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, bar-chart, wide-format-data

I want to display `total` and `available` bars side by side for each `fruit`.

Here is the data I'm using

```
import plotly.express as px

data_frame = {
    "fruits": ["orange", "apple", "banana", "cherry"],
    "total": [10, 20, 30, 25],
    "available": [7, 10, 27, 15],
}
```

And I used `plotly.express` as follow:

```
fig = px.bar(
    data_frame,
    x="fruits",
    y=["total", "available"],
    color="fruits",
    barmode="group", # Is ignored
)

fig.show()
```

However, bars are still shown in `stack` mode instead. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a way to do this without changing your data from wide to long format, but I think it's more intuitive to melt your dataframe so that you have `variable` and `value` columns using:

```
df_melted = df.melt(id_vars='fruits', value_vars=['total','available'])
```

This gives you the following long format dataframe.

```
   fruits   variable  value
0  orange      total     10
1   apple      total     20
2  banana      total     30
3  cherry      total     25
4  orange  available      7
5   apple  available     10
6  banana  available     27
7  cherry  available     15
```

Then you can create the bar chart using:

```
fig = px.bar(df_melted, x='fruits', y='value', color='variable', barmode='group')
```

This will allow plotly to differentiate the between `total` and `available` bars within each `fruit`.

[image]